# Angular $http POST sending empty object as body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, body-parser

I have some pretty vanilla code, but can't seem to figure out the issue.  On the server side, I get an empty object in the body of the request when sending the POST below. I'm using express on the server side. My server side works fine when I use Postman, so the server side isn't the issue as far as I can tell.  From everything I can find, the code below should work just fine:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/authRequest',
    headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
    body: {
        'test' : 'test'
    }
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try use **tyle: "post"**

Comment: "On the server side, I get an empty object in the body of the request" — Where is your server side code? How are you examining the body of the request?

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your browser to look at the raw HTTP request? Is it formatted as you expect? Does it use the method you expect?

Comment: in angular $http there is no such property`body` it looks that you must read the official documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.
The correct property is the `data` one

Comment: @HoangHieu — I looked at [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). I don't see any mention of `tyle` (or `type` for that matter). `method` is correct.

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

There is no such parameter as 'body' in post request. You should use 'data':

```
$http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost:5000/authRequest',
              headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
              data: {'test' : 'test'}
}).then(function(response){
   // your logic for viewing
});
```

Comment: Geez. Thanks.  Step 0: read the documentation and pay attention.  Switched "body" to "data" and it works fine.